# Is *this = Ctor(); legal and efficient for clearing an object's state?

Tags: c++, constructor, language-lawyer, c++17, this-pointer

I've stumbled across this piece of code to reestablish class invariants:

```
class Foo {
  // some stuff in here
public:
  void clear() {
    *this = Foo();
    //operator=(Foo()); // commented out in favor of the line above
  }
};
```

- I would assume that the call to `operator=` is legal and works as expected, but will create an unnecessary temporary, **in case the class is not movable**. So it would probably be more efficient to manually assign default values, which is cumbersome and error-prone if we want to extend the class.
- `*this = Foo()`, if allowed, is probably more efficient, as copy elision could work here I assume (regardless of the class being movable).

So my questions are:

- Is the statement `*this = Foo();` legal? If yes, please provide a reference to the standard
- What is more efficient (providing that the first bullet point is true)?
- In case `Foo` is movable.
- In case it's not.

Comment: Why do you think the statement shouldn't be legal? It' s a simple assignment.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ because we're overwriting the content referred to by `*this`. I'm not sure if RAII works properly here (i.e. if the current object gets properly destroyed before the new one is assigned etc.) or if there are other side effects. That's why I'm asking :-)

Comment: Of course this is guaranteed for a simple assignment `Foo f, g; f = g;`, but since `*this` is not a "normal" variable I'm not quite sure if that's allowed.

Comment: _"`*this` is not a "normal" variable"_ Dereferencing `this` works like with any other pointer.

Comment: it is simply an assignment from object of type foo with a new object of foo which results in calling the copy assignment operator. So what is special here? The question is more, if it is a good idea to write such code if user here on so needs 6 comments to get the point :-)

Comment: Assignment does not destroy the object being assigned to. (Unless your custom implementation does it explicitly, in which case it should be rewritten to not do that.)

Comment: @Klaus: I paraphrased the question title to make my intent clearer - I actually already assumed it's legal, but still I wonder what's the right way to go for clearing the object.

Comment: @andreee: It is absolutely legal to create a "clean" temporary and overwrite the "own" instance with it in the (automatic generated) copy assignment operator. And the temporary has a good to chance to optimized away. But you also can use a Init() function which can be called from ctor and you clear() function. But this has also drawbacks like using references can not be changed in Init and so on.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks, FWIW, that's also a satisfactory answer :-) Sometimes the absence of facts in the standard is also good to know...

Comment: @andreee I can tun my comment into an answer, if you think it's worth it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think I'm still not yet sure about what solution will work better (or if there's an even better/cleaner solution for clearing an object's state).

Comment: I’m tempted to write an answer mentioning in-place destruction followed by placement-new but since that’s generally a bad idea I’ll just note it in this comment for completeness. Do use the `*this` assignment.

Comment: Presumably the `operator=` properly handles resource management (if any), then that assignment to a default constructed unnamed object will do the right thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> - Is the statement `*this = Foo();` legal? If yes, please provide a reference to the standard

That's legal yes. It follows the standard that the value can be assigned through a dereferenced pointer.

I don't think we can find anything in the c++-standard mentioning the situation, since it's not a *special situation* as you think it is.
Assigning a dereferenced `*this` pointer works as with any other pointer.

> - What is more efficient (providing that the first bullet point is true)?
>
>   - In case `Foo` is movable.
>   - In case it's not.

There are no differences regarding efficiency. Copy elision will be taken by any decent modern c++ compiler.

Comment: I believe that the chances of copy elision are slim to none. If the constructor throws an exception, `*this` should not change state. Therefore the new instance of `Foo` must be constructed first, then assigned. And if there is no move-assignment operator, how do you elide the copy? Maybe if the construct is `noexcept`, `*this` can be destroyed first before being constructed in place.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It depends on what that constructor is doing. If constant propagation is enough to prove that the constructor or destructor don't have side effects (no dynamic memory allocations for instance) the copy can be elided, otherwise it can't.